# Rational functions on an affinoid subset of $\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: number-theory, nonarchimedian-analysis, rigid-analytic-spaces

In Van der Put's Rigid analytic geometry and its applications, he's trying to define holomorphic functions on an affinoid subset of $\mathbb{P}^1/K$ as follows, where $(K, |\cdot|)$ is an algebraically closed, complete non-Archimedean field.

[image]

I'm wondering why such an $f$ has bounded absolute value on $F$. My argument is like:

Suppose $F\subsetneq \mathbb{P}^1$, then it is contained in a closed disk, say of the form $B = \{a\in K: |a|\leq r\}$ with $r\in |K^*|$. Write $f = g/h$ as a quotient of polynomials in the lowest form. Then $g$ clearly has bounded absolute value on $B$ and hence on $F$. We can use a similar argument as in real analysis to show that $h$ is bounded too; $h$ is clearly continuous on $F$, hence attains a non-zero minimum on $F$ if provided that $F$ is compact. But I feel like this argument only holds if every closed disks are compact, which I'm not sure if it is true in general, say if $K$ is not locally compact.

I'm wondering if there are other arguments without using the compactness of closed disks. Also, is $\mathbb{P}^1$ compact w.r.t. the ordinary topology induced from $(K,|\cdot|)$?

Comment: I probably figured out what's going on. This should follows from the non-archimedean property. For example, take $F = \bar{B}(0,1)$ the closed disk of radius 1 centered at 0. Take $g = 1, h = z-a$ with $a\notin F$. Then, $1<|a| = |a-z+z|\leq \max\{|z-a|,|z|\}$, implying $|z-a|>1$ whenever $z\in F$.